# Installation of Hyper-V on Windows 10 home

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, kali-linux, hyper-v-manager

How can I install Hyper-V on Windows 10 Home? I have downloaded Kali Linux and am trying to run it on Oracle Virtual Box but it is saying that VT-x is not available. I have 64-bit CPU with SLAT and Virtualization ON in the BIOS.

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Hyper-V cannot be installed on Windows 10 Home. Do you have an AMD CPU? I've heard of issues with virtualization on non-Intel CPUs.

Comment: Try VMWare Player, this might get past the issue.

Comment: I have Intel CPU.

Comment: @Todd Is VMWare safe ? If so, can you give me the link ?

Comment: @AbhayRao VMWare is COMPLETLEY safe from a security perspective!!! Here is the [link](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html). Make sure you have Windows Defender Credential Guard disabled. I don’t even think it’s available on Windows 10 Home but just FYI.

Comment: may be relevent https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=94202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft article
[Install Hyper-V on Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)
says this:

> The Hyper-V role **cannot** be installed on Windows 10 Home.

The bold "cannot" is in the original text.

You need to upgrade to Pro.

Comment: May you help me with this please ! https://superuser.com/q/1555576/1180053