# Unable to login in Kali Linux after mounting Virtual Box Guest Addition File to open in full screen

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux, fullscreen

How can I fix this issue? It occured after **mounting Virtual Box Guest Addition file into Kali Linux to open in full screen**. I can't login now. As I click on login, a massage shows-- **VBoxClient : Failed to register**
[image]

Comment: The text "VBoxClient : Failed to register" should include some following text that might better indicate the problem. This error may be connected to configured virtual hardware that is not supported on Kali. Try to include more details from the error message, and let us know with which hardware controllers/devices you configured the VM.

Comment: I could see only this. It occurred after mounting Virtual Box Guest Addition File and after rebooting the machine

Comment: You are missing the whole message here. See the Troubleshooting section [Collecting Debugging Information](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html#collect-debug-info).

Comment: @harrymc How can I do it ?

Comment: Follow the linked text.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too when I tried to make it fullscreen. Turns out it was because the linux system I had installed on my vm was 32 bit while my host machine is 64 bit. After downloading and installing the 64 bit kali linux and mounting Virtual Box Guest Addition file to make it fullscreen, the problem wasn't there anymore when I restarted the machine